# Visual Studio 2017 Installation breaks Windows 10 (on a MacBook Pro)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017, bootcamp

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation on my MacBook Pro (Late 2016) along with the newest Bootcamp drivers. Everything is working and shiny up until now.

When I install Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise it works up to a point where the reboot takes place. This takes really long, but windows is starting again, for about 7 minutes windows boots while showing the loading indicator. When I'm finally prompted for Login, the MacBooks keyboard and trackpad doesn't work anymore, as we'll as I don't have a wifi connection or audio (having the x sign in taskbar).

I tried the whole painfull process three times now while ending up with the same problem. Windows is broken, which means I can't reinstall the bootcamp drivers (crashes system), no system restore points can be restored (failing), I can't reset windows (breaks the boot process and results in a blank screen). I guess this is somehow related to an intercompatibility between bootcamp and Visual Studio 2017.

I'm not sure if this is related to any specific components of VisualStudio which I install. I'll try a minimal install next...

Comment: Just curious.  Did you run "diskclean" inside Windows before installing 2017?

Comment: @JoeHealy No, I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the same for me, Windows 10 was loading 5-8 minutes and no keyboard and touchpad support. After 3-5 re-installs(windows and VS2017), found that issue caused by Hyper-V virtualization. It is disabled by default, but as soon as you installed VS 2017 with at least one component which require Hyper-V, you will never be able to login to you windows on macbook pro.
Just DO NOT install any emulators:
Google Android emulator,
Intel hardware accelerated execution manager(HAXM),
Visual Studio emulator for Android,
Windows 10 Mobile Emulator

And Windows will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. That was indeed the problem. I'm heavily in need of Hyper-V, so not installing is not an option. The problem has actually originated from Apple dropping support of Legacy BIOS for MacBooks since 2015 and Hyper-Vs lacking support of UEFI only systems. So my solution actually was to buy a used 2014 MacBook as I'm in need of Hyper-V and Mac OS for Cross Platform development. I hope Microsoft will support modern hardware soon so I can upgrade to a new MacBook ;-)